# how to get the absolute url of a view in django?

Tags: python, django

I have a view called "callback" in views.py.
How can I get the absolute url with domain for that view?

I tried using:

```
request.build_absolute_url(reverse('authorize'))
```

but that did not work.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
request.get_host() + reverse('authorize')
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is [`build_absolute_uri`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri) not `build_absolute_url`